# Is there a way to get json keys without using inline js

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

In Logic Apps, is there a way using standard blocks to get from a .json object like this:
{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3} to an array of keys like this: ["a", "b", "c"]? Any help appreciated.

Comment: Is this a Azure problem? Describe more about problem, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to achieve your needs. If you don’t like to use inline code, you can directly look at the second method, but I recommend you to use inline code because it is really much simpler

**1.** Inline Code

If you are not familiar with inline code, you can study this [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-add-run-inline-code). This is the workflow of logic apps I designed for you：

[image]

What you need to pay attention to is that using inline code requires an integration account. Please search for integration account in Azure portal:

[image]

Select `Add` to create a new `integration account`:
[image]

Click `Review+Create` to create a integration account.
[image]

In logic apps, select the integration account you create:
[image]

I have tested it for you and the result is expected.
[image]

**2.** The second way is to split the string, which is more cumbersome

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

The final test results can also meet expectations:
[image]