# logic app convert json to key value pair json

Tags: json, azure, azure-logic-apps

Looking forward to an approach to convert simple JSON objects to Key value pair JSON objects using **Logic Apps**.
Like:

```
{
            "FirstName": "ABC",
            "LastName": "123",
            "MiddleName": null,
}
```

to

```
  [
    {
        "Key": "FirstName"
        "Value": "ABC"
    },
    {
        "Key": "LastName"
        "Value": "123"
    }
 ]
```

Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: Yep … https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/advanceddataoperatio/, more specifically … https://www.statesolutions.com.au/json-properties-to-name-value-pair-array/

Answer (score 0):

I have followed the below steps to convert JSON Object to Key-Value pair JSON Objects-

1. Created one "**When a HTTP request is received**" as below

[image]

2. Add a Parse Json action.
   I have taken `triggerBody()` in the **Content** field

[image]

Here Schema is

```
{
"properties": {
"FirstName": {
"type": "string"
},
"LastName": {
"type": "string"
},
"MiddleName": {
"type": "string"
}
},
"type": "object"
}
```

3. After the Parse JSON action, add a **Compose** action.
   Enter the following expression in the **Inputs** field of the Compose action

   ```
    [
    {
            "Key": "FirstName",
            "Value": "@{body('Parse_JSON')['FirstName']}"
    },
    {
            "Key": "LastName",
            "Value": "@{body('Parse_JSON')['LastName']}"
    },
    {
            "Key": "MiddleName",
            "Value": "@{body('Parse_JSON')['MiddleName']}"
    }
    ]
   ```

[image]

4. Save and Run the logic app.

**Output**-

[image]

[image]

Check in the **Runs History**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply.. But it won't work if a new node gets added in the inbound message like:

{
            "FirstName": "ABC",
            "LastName": "123",
            "MiddleName": null,
   "Age": 30
}

then expected outputs would be:
[
    {
        "Key": "FirstName"
        "Value": "ABC"
    },
    {
        "Key": "LastName"
        "Value": "123"
    },
     {
        "Key": "Age"
        "Value": 30
    }
 ]

Comment: try referring this SO question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63795368/is-there-a-way-to-get-json-keys-without-using-inline-js

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment, you should (could) look at using the `Advanced Data Operations` connector, it has an operation which is specifically designed to complete your requirement.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/advanceddataoperatio/

https://www.statesolutions.com.au/json-properties-to-name-value-pair-array/

[image: Flow]

This is the resulting JSON it will give back ...

```
[
  {
    "propertyName": "FirstName",
    "propertyType": "String",
    "propertyValue": "ABC"
  },
  {
    "propertyName": "LastName",
    "propertyType": "String",
    "propertyValue": "123"
  },
  {
    "propertyName": "MiddleName",
    "propertyType": "Null",
    "propertyValue": null
  }
]
```