# JSON properties in to an array (are all jobs complete)

Tags: azure-logic-apps

The JSON below comes from an entity on table storage.
There will be more "item" properties added and removed over time - they represent whether a job has completed or not. My goal is to understand when all jobs have completed.

In a Logic App I check if any items are false. I won't know the name of the "item" in advance.

I'm looking for a method to map the JSON properties in to an array. Is there such a method or is there another way?

{
"odata.etag": "W/"datetime'2024-02-22T14%3A28%3A16.3091774Z'"",
"PartitionKey": "2024",
"RowKey": "08584929947924424952570595495CU00",
"Timestamp": "2024-02-22T14:28:16.3091774+00:00",
"item-001": "false",
"item-002": "false",
}

Comment: Yep … https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76470794/logic-app-convert-json-to-key-value-pair-json/76510795#76510795

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could run a [JavaScript code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-add-run-inline-code?tabs=standard) snippet in your workflow, e.g.

```
let obj = workflowContext.actions.Compose.outputs;
let arr = Object.keys(obj).map(key => ({name: key, value: obj[key]}));
return arr;
```

This is what it would look like:
[image]

[image]

[image]